# Process child XML elements with Python Pandas read_xml

Tags: python, pandas, xml, lxml, elementtree

I'm trying to load some XML data into Python Pandas, I have never had to deal
with XML before but unfortunately it's the only way I can get the data.  I've
looked around but the way this data is organised doesn't follow most examples
so I'm struggling to translate tutorials into my use case.

Here is a truncated form of the data structure.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xsi:schemaLocation="Trend_x0020_Report http://localhost/ReportServer_ION?%2FION%20Reports%2FION%20Report%20Packs%2FDefault%20Reports%2FTrend%20Report&amp;rs%3AFormat=XML&amp;rc%3ASchema=True" Name="Trend Report" textbox3="Report Data Table" textbox15="ID: 6e5dff70-8a91-48c0-b1db-29f6a43b73dc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="Trend_x0020_Report">
    <matrix1 textbox28="Timestamp">
        <TimestampGroup_Collection>
            <TimestampGroup textbox30="01/08/2021 00:15:00">
                <SourcesGroup_Collection>
                    <SourcesGroup textbox29="Datacenter.BankA">
                        <MeasurementGroup_Collection>
                            <MeasurementGroup textbox32="C1_L1_Amps ()">
                                <Cell textbox5="10.15" />
                            </MeasurementGroup>
                        </MeasurementGroup_Collection>
                    </SourcesGroup>
                    <SourcesGroup textbox29="Datacenter.BankB">
                        <MeasurementGroup_Collection>
                            <MeasurementGroup textbox32="C1_L1_Amps ()">
                                <Cell textbox5="10.05" />
                            </MeasurementGroup>
                        </MeasurementGroup_Collection>
                    </SourcesGroup>
                </SourcesGroup_Collection>
            </TimestampGroup>
            <TimestampGroup textbox30="01/08/2021 00:30:00">
                <SourcesGroup_Collection>
                    <SourcesGroup textbox29="Datacenter.BankA">
                        <MeasurementGroup_Collection>
                            <MeasurementGroup textbox32="C1_L1_Amps ()">
                                <Cell textbox5="11.51" />
                            </MeasurementGroup>
                        </MeasurementGroup_Collection>
                    </SourcesGroup>
                    <SourcesGroup textbox29="Datacenter.BankB">
                        <MeasurementGroup_Collection>
                            <MeasurementGroup textbox32="C1_L1_Amps ()">
                                <Cell textbox5="11.27" />
                            </MeasurementGroup>
                        </MeasurementGroup_Collection>
                    </SourcesGroup>
                </SourcesGroup_Collection>
            </TimestampGroup>
        </TimestampGroup_Collection>
    </matrix1>
</Report>
```

I'd like the data to appear as a Pandas DataFrame object like this:

[image: Desired df]

An example of the desired DataFrame as a Python Dictionary:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {
    "datetime": ["01/08/2021 00:15:00", "01/08/2021 00:30:00"],
    "Datacenter.BankA": [10.15, 10.05],
    "Datacenter.BankB": [11.51, 11.27]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

If I load the XML as-is with

```py
df = pd.DataFrame('/path/to/xml')
```

Pandas seems to do its best to interpret the data but stops at the single key
under `Report`, rather than process the child keys under `matrix1`.

I've tried various combinations of `read_xml` options, such as `elems_only=True`
in order to process the child elements but I'm not getting anywhere.

I'm thinking that perhaps I need to create a style sheet to describe the data
format but have no idea where to start - any advice welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, the below is what you are looking for. Not exactly what you have posted.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict

import pandas as pd

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report 
        xsi:schemaLocation="Trend_x0020_Report http://localhost/ReportServer_ION?%2FION%20Reports%2FION%20Report%20Packs%2FDefault%20Reports%2FTrend%20Report&amp;rs%3AFormat=XML&amp;rc%3ASchema=True" 
        Name="Trend Report" textbox3="Report Data Table" textbox15="ID: 6e5dff70-8a91-48c0-b1db-29f6a43b73dc" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="Trend_x0020_Report">
    <matrix1 textbox28="Timestamp">
        <TimestampGroup_Collection>
            <TimestampGroup textbox30="01/08/2021 00:15:00">
                <SourcesGroup_Collection>
                    <SourcesGroup textbox29="Datacenter.BankA">
                        <MeasurementGroup_Collection>
                            <MeasurementGroup textbox32="C1_L1_Amps ()">
                                <Cell textbox5="10.15" />
                            </MeasurementGroup>
                        </MeasurementGroup_Collection>
                    </SourcesGroup>
                    <SourcesGroup textbox29="Datacenter.BankB">
                        <MeasurementGroup_Collection>
                            <MeasurementGroup textbox32="C1_L1_Amps ()">
                                <Cell textbox5="10.05" />
                            </MeasurementGroup>
                        </MeasurementGroup_Collection>
                    </SourcesGroup>
                </SourcesGroup_Collection>
            </TimestampGroup>
            <TimestampGroup textbox30="01/08/2021 00:30:00">
                <SourcesGroup_Collection>
                    <SourcesGroup textbox29="Datacenter.BankA">
                        <MeasurementGroup_Collection>
                            <MeasurementGroup textbox32="C1_L1_Amps ()">
                                <Cell textbox5="11.51" />
                            </MeasurementGroup>
                        </MeasurementGroup_Collection>
                    </SourcesGroup>
                    <SourcesGroup textbox29="Datacenter.BankB">
                        <MeasurementGroup_Collection>
                            <MeasurementGroup textbox32="C1_L1_Amps ()">
                                <Cell textbox5="11.27" />
                            </MeasurementGroup>
                        </MeasurementGroup_Collection>
                    </SourcesGroup>
                </SourcesGroup_Collection>
            </TimestampGroup>
        </TimestampGroup_Collection>
    </matrix1>
</Report>'''

NS = "Trend_x0020_Report"
data = defaultdict(list)
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
timestamps = root.findall(f'.//{{{NS}}}TimestampGroup')
for ts in timestamps:
    date = ts.attrib['textbox30']
    data['datetime'].append(date)
    for grp in ts.findall(f'.//{{{NS}}}SourcesGroup'):
        bank_name = grp.attrib['textbox29']
        cell = grp.find(f'.//{{{NS}}}Cell').attrib['textbox5']
        data[bank_name].append(cell)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

output

```
              datetime Datacenter.BankA Datacenter.BankB
0  01/08/2021 00:15:00            10.15            10.05
1  01/08/2021 00:30:00            11.51            11.27
```

Comment: That's amazing thank you.  As Pandas `read_xml` can use ET as an import engine I feel sure there's a way to do it that way, but I think I'm just going to try and understand your code example.